# nodejs + websocket session confusion

Tags: node.js, session, express, sockjs

I'm really confused how to set up sessions with my nodejs application. I'm using express + socksjs and I have trouble understanding how to bind the ws connection to specific user session.

On the sockjs page they say not to use cookies for authorization but if I don't send the session from the cookie when establishing the ws connection (the cookie with session set earlier by express) how can I bind that specific ws connection with specific user?

I'd like to achieve these simple goals:
- User (logged in or guest) visits the page and establishes ws connection
- I store in redis the key value pair of connection id and session so I know which user given ws connection belongs to

How to do that if I can't send the session from cookie just after establishing the ws connection? Even if I wanted, the cookie is not available due to being HttpOnly and thus not readable through js.

edit:

[this google group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sockjs/ZWOfnpOexa0/zcmWzsDvrbIJ) suggests that I send encrypted user details in first message which sounds good but still I'm not sure where I should take those details from. I've always done it via sessions and cookies...

Comment: While I was struggling with this problem, this blog post helped me: [socket-io-and-express-3](http://notjustburritos.tumblr.com/post/22682186189/socket-io-and-express-3)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio.  I've used it and it's pretty straightforward to get going.

Answer (score 0):

For session restoring Cookies are used in most cases. SockJS does allow use of cookies, but just using raw cookies without any other security practices - is a bit scary, especially if your SockJS is on another domain and cookies will have uncertain Origin scope.

Consider using Token method for authentication.

If you really need to use cookies please read this, all reasoning is there, and I wont just duplicate already explained situation: https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/pull/29#issuecomment-2733120